# jQuery match all instances of a character in a string

Tags: jquery, regex

Having a hard time with this one, should be easy!.. But alass...

I have this string:

```
<b>LARGE TYPE/BIOGRAPHY/956.704434/LUTTRELL,M</b>
```

Im trying to replace all / with a / and space between, making

```
<b>LARGE TYPE / BIOGRAPHY / 956.704434 / LUTTRELL,M</b>
```

Ive got this so far:

```
$('b').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('/', ' / ')); 
});
```

But this is only matching the first instance of the /

Ive done some research, and it would seem I need to add a g for global, but no matter how I try, it never matches all. Im sure its my syntax, putting the g in incorrectly.

Can anyone help me build this correctly?
RegEx has never been a strong suit of mine.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression with [the g flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags):

```
$(this).text(text.replace(/\//g, ' / '));
```

Comment: That did it.. Why escape the g twice?
I did try $(this).text(text.replace(/\/g, ' / '));

Comment: @Jason I don't escape the g, but the `/` because `/` is the regex literal delimiter (see link).